# getting error: yards supports a minimum Node.js version of 12 after doing npm install for webdriverio

Tags: node.js

I am working with webdriverio and all my scripts were running fine until a ran npm install after which getting the following error when trying to rum my scripts in visual studio code command line:
yards supports a minimum Node.js version of 12
Does this mean I need to update node.js to version 12?

Answer (score 3):

I was able to resolve this by updating Node.js to the current version.

Answer (score 0):

The issue said that the min node version supported by yargs is node 12. In my case I was using node 10, so you would need to use node 12 or later.